# Cant login in Mysql Command Line

Tags: mysql, mysql-cli

[enter image description here][1]
Hello I´m trying to use Mysql Command Line (8.0) and all tutorials begin with the command
`mysql -uroot -p` or `mysql -u root -p` or some variant in order to connect, and then they enter the password.
But for me I only get a `->` where I can type anything but nothing happens.
I reallize that this is a basic question but i just can´t seem to figure out what i´m doing wrong.
Thanks.

### Edit:

As @Progman pointed out i´m logged in from the get-go. Since i dind´t see the name "root" in the terminal i assumed i was logged out. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Have you set a username and password? Wgen you say `->` do you mean you get a prompt? Try something there like `show databases;`

Comment: Usually nothing shows up as you type your password, but as soon as you hit enter, it should either log you in or tell you that your password is wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete content of your command line to show, what you are talking about. Include everything that is visible so we can see the context in how/where you try to execute these commands.

Comment: @doctorlove Yes, for both root and for a custom user. Using the workbench i can connect just fine. Trying any other command results in the same.

Comment: @prakasht In the tutorials it apears something like "Enter password:" and then when they enter the password the letters are hidden with a *. But for me it´s just the -> and everything appears in plain text

Comment: @SamV It looks like you are already inside the MySQL client. You don't need to "run" the command `mysql ...` anymore. Instead you can begin running SQL statements.

Comment: @Progman Indeed. I was expecting for the username "root" or such to appear. Since it dind´t i assumed I was logged out. I feel silly. Thanks for the help .